# Voting button not showing on Windows 10 Lock Screen

Tags: windows-10, lock-screen, windows-spotlight

on my Desktop PC I have Spotlight enabled and the background images on the lock screen change every day. However the"voting" button is not shown (Like what you see?). I like that feature because you can find out where the picture was taken hovering over the button.
The version is Windows 10 Pro v. 1607. 
I read that the workaround is to change the following:

`Interactive logon: Do not require CTRL+ALT+DEL`

change from Disabled to Enabled

However, this is not feasible for me, I'm on a domain and I can't.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you talked to your domian Administrator about changing the group policy so the Like button is enabled?  To answer your question, the solution (not a work around) to the problem, is to Enable that group policy.  There are also other appliciable policies that must be set.  **In conclusion:** *You cannot enable the Windows Spotlight Like button, without being an Administrator, on the domain itself.*

Comment: Typically we are glad to help whenever possible, but in this type of scenario you really should consult your IT support staff.  It is their Windows 10 system configuration.

Comment: @Run5k I'll go and speak to them. But it looks like that policy is disabled for security reasons.

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks for your answer. I'll go and speak but it looks unlikely since it's a security measure. I was wondering why you need to disable it.

Comment: When that Group Policy is set to `Disabled`, then you *are* required to use `CTRL+ALT+DEL` to log into your machine.  That is a standard domain workstation configuration.

Comment: @peval27 - The Administrator of the domain decided the the policy should be disabled not enabled.

Comment: @Run5k Yeah, I understood that, even before I asked the question. My question was about why you need to enable that group policy for using this Windows 10 feature...

Comment: @Ramhound see my comment above

Comment: In other words, having that Group Policy disabled on a domain workstation seems to prevent usage of some of the "interactive features" that can be normally be utilized on a Windows 10 lock screen at home.

Comment: @peval27 - I saw it.  Does not change my comment.